# Organically learning or creating shortcuts and gestures for arbitrary actions

Tags: macos, shortcut

Keyboard shortcuts across OS X and applications are an amazing productivity booster that have proven to be worthwhile, notwithstanding the sometimes arduous task of first memorizing them.

Is there a setting, app, or hack of some sort that would allow me to go about my business as usual and display any extant key combination as actions I perform match mapped shortcuts? This would stimulate passive learning of keyboard shortcuts -- and for ones most relevant to the user no less! Keep track of my actions so that I could assign shortcuts to series of actions would really be something.

What aspects of the OS libraries available could a developer use write such software?

*Something like seeing the shortcut next to the menu item, only when the menu isn't used...  e.g. something that would flash "Command + L" each time I click the address bar of a browser, or "Command + Shift + D" each time I clicked "Send" on a mail message.*

Comment: I would like to see that as well, it would be very helpful, sort of a short cut to show shortcuts in a particular application.

Comment: For development of such an app, I think 'watch me do' within automator or the Accessibility Inspector application in the Developer Tools are a good place to start. It logs your event by name (e.g. 'New window'). You can than search the keyboard shortcuts for the same name and display the shortcut to the user.

Answer (score 1):

## Menu items contain shortcut information

Mightbe a bit obvious, but most of the menu items contain shortcut information. And if no shortcut is visible for a specific menu item, it is most certain that none is available.

When you use a menu item, do not click, but use the shortcut instead.

You can also create you own shortcuts, but that is something different.

Comment: My apologies, I stopped short of mentioning that I knew this and was looking for something different. In fact, making my own shortcuts for items is something I would like. I am going to tune the question up a little for that.

Comment: Why apologies? I already thought you were familiar with the shortcuts within the menu's. But, although this is not the right anser to your question, it should be mentioned within the answers.